# Error while creating folder

Tags: php, directory

I am trying to create folder like this

```
$destination = "../folder_name/_pcode/../_compile";
mkdir($destination);
```

But this gives error

**UPDATE**
What i am doing is, taking `../folder_name/_pcode` as input from user and I want to create a folder outside the `_pcode` Directory

**Here is my error**

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in G:\wamp\www\tools\compile.php on line 57
../folder_name/_pcode/../_compile
```

Comment: How about using some quotes? `"../enumesis.com....."`

Comment: This code won't even compile. Please add quotes first.

Comment: Aside from the obvious lack of quotes, it's always useful to specify **which** error you're getting. It usually exactly tells what the problem is.

Comment: btw: isn't `../enumesis.com/_pcode/../_compile` and `../enumesis.com/_compile` exactly the same?

Comment: sorry, I typed the question in an hurry, I have updated it

Comment: @acmatos, ../enumesis.com/_pcode is a user input, so I can't tweak it like that

Comment: @Starx as kemp says, you still need to give us the error. "Bananas missing", "Permissions invalid" or whatever - that tells us how to help you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely that you're trying to create a subdirectory within a non-existing directory, in this case, if you want to create the whole directory path, try setting `mkdir`'s `$recursive` parameter to `true`:

```
mkdir($destination, 0777, true);
```